# Why assert macro makes use only for debug build

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assert

Why is this a common practice to have `assert` macro do something useful only in debug configuration? If it exists to test invariants and detect coding bugs, then would not it be easier to go ahead and do the same big boom in production software?

I have some S60 background and there exist `__ASSERT_ALWAYS` and `__ASSERT_DEBUG`, where the latter is equivalent to `assert`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checking for assertion costs. You have extra operations that you may not want to exist in the final product. If assertions were always going to work, then people would start using them less "to not kill performance". And believe me, there are a *lot* of people out there who consider the extra checks a *performance kill* and would avoid it. These are the same people who actually have to use assert more!

A more important reason is that, `assert`, if failed, will just abort your program. There is no usefulness in that whatsoever for the end user (except perhaps for security, to avoid running code with unexpected data, but that's arguably better handled by actual error checking). If you want your program to actually terminate with a message or do something useful, you would have to write your own assert. In that case, you can of course choose to keep it in release mode also.

Finally, assertion helps you find bugs, especially hidden bugs, but in the execution of the software, they may actually not happen. Imagine the following code:

```
struct X
{
    // other stuff
    int stage;
};

X x;
... do some stuff
assert(x.stage == STAGE_2);
x.stage = STAGE_3; // go to next stage
... do more stuff
```

In such an example, your logic says `x` should be in `STAGE_2`. If it is not, it's a bug. However, if you remove the assert, fix `x.stage` and move on, there is hope that the bug is not so severe. In such a case, the end-user can actually continue working without noticing this. If you had kept `assert` in release mode too, you would force the application to exit over a bug that didn't have any visible effect.

In reality, you get updates all the times for your software, in which they claim they have fixed bugs. Some of those, are indeed bugs that `assert` would have caught. However, you as the end-user didn't have any problem and were actually happy that you weren't interrupted due to those `assert`s, weren't you?

Comment: Stage 1 : start the car, Stage 2: check there's nobody in the way, Stage 3 : drive!  - So if we skip stage 2, no problem? ;-) I understand what you're saying, but in general it's not a good idea to continue regardless after an assert fails.

Comment: @roddy, I think we have different ideas of what should be asserted. For example, output of `malloc` is not something I would assert, but ensuring my left-rotate operation on an AVL tree didn't make the tree unbalanced is something I would do with `assert`. The difference is that the first is an error that should be handled, otherwise bad things happen, the second one, at worst creates a performance problem.

Comment: I agree - Your AVL tree is a good example as verifying the balance could be a comparatively slow operation. I'd rather see an assert() on a malloc call than no checking at all (although most apps have no useful way to handle malloc failures). Of course in C++ `new` failures would throw instead...

Comment: @roddy, I hear you. Personally, I don't have a single program/library that doesn't check `malloc`'s output. I always check stuff that _can_ go wrong within the program itself. What _can't possibly go wrong_..., I still check within the program. What can't possibly go wrong, but if does it doesn't really matter, I `assert` them.

Comment: I guess it would be fair to accept this answer after all. Programmers are (and have to be) idealists or else they wont achieve the best results. I value this answer for its taste of real life though. Cheers

Answer (score 18):

Asserts are made for stuff that should **never happen**, i.e. if it does then there is a bug in your code that you need to fix. Releases are builds that are "supposed" to be bug free, and killing application with the assert for the user is as bad as any other faulty behavior.

Comment: The application is dead either way. But without the assert, the developers have no useful way of debugging it. Fail fast...

Comment: @roddy, fail fast, but not in the face of the user ;)

Comment: @Shahbaz - you're failing in the face of the user anyway. Best to fail early and predictably than struggle on assuming that the buffer overrun you ignored won't matter *that* much...

Comment: @roddy, best to fail using your own custom `assert` that doesn't give the user a hearth attack. I'm not saying "remove error checking from code", I'm saying "don't use `assert()` for it".

Comment: @Shahbaz - semi-custom... - BOOST_ASSERT : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/assert.html

Comment: @roddy, nevertheless, checking for buffer overflow is not something you would do in an assert!!!

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a cultural thing. The arguments in favour removing this kind of check in production code go like this:

- It makes your code run slower.
- It makes the final executable larger.
- Your code shouldn't have bugs in once it ships.
- It will cause your program to exit suddenly and violently, with possible loss of data.

The arguments against run as follows

- You're shipping the *exact* code that you tested.
- Debugging problems reported in the field gets much easier
- Regardless of what you'd like to think, the code you ship **WILL** have bugs
- Performance and size effects are typically minimal.
- Failing fast may be preferable to attempting to continue when your program is in an undesired state.

Personally, I ship software that's built exactly as it's tested, asserts and all. But, a lot depends on your customer base and how you hope to schedule releases...

This article is worth a read:- http://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf

> but what about when you deploy the software to customers? We don’t
>   want the application to crash just because there’s a typo in a
>   configuration file. One reaction to this fear is to disable assertions
>   in the field.
>
> Don’t do that! Remember, an error that occurs at the
>   customer’s site made it through your testing process. You’ll probably
>   have trouble reproducing it. These errors are the hardest to find, and
>   a well-placed assertion explaining the problem could save you days of
>   effort.

One other thing - in C++, using [BOOST_ASSERT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/assert.html) you can set it to throw an exception on assertion failure, which makes handling and potentially recovering from assertion failures even more useful. we use this in conjunction with [MadExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) so that any assert failures in the field can be easily posted by the user into our bug tracker, with complete call stacks, screenshots, whathaveyou.

Comment: Unfortunately, in a harsh world of capitalist sharks hardly reproducible bugs are hardly worth any effort

Comment: @RomanSaveljev - I disagree: The commercial impact of a bug can be totally unrelated to how easy it is to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

`assert` works unless you explicitly turn it off.  There's (usually) no
reason to turn it off, even in "release" builds, and most of the
released code I've delivered has had `assert` active.

The main reason for turning it off is performance.  In this case, you
turn it off very locally, in the function where the performance is
critical, with something like:

```
#ifdef TURNOFFCRITICALASSERTS
#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
#endif

//  Function with critical code here...

#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
```

This is the way the C standards committee designed `assert` to be used.
Generally, you should not define `NDEBUG` except locally, like this.